# Reading certificate in certificate store using PHP

Tags: php, ssl

How can I read a secure certificate in windows certificate store from PHP (running IIS)

I know how to read it from a certificate file, but I am trying to read it directly from the certificate store.

is this able to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly supported by PHP. You may be able to utilize one of the [Win32 PECL](http://pecl.php.net/packages.php?catpid=37&catname=System) extensions to call the required functions in Windows.

If these don't support what you need, you may have to write your own extension.